# how to "generate" link in javascript based on dropdown selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 different dropdowns with different items user can choose from. upon selecting all 3 and confirming, a link should generate and be stored inside "paypal" < a > tag.

```
<div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    XBOX
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="ddvalue1" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" value="xbox">xbox</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" value="ps4">ps4</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" value="pc">pc</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Rest of the code **

https://jsfiddle.net/t722qhq0/9/

Let me make one scenario:

User chooses xbox for instance, the next dropdown shows the games available on xbox...let's say there's only pes18 and fifa18 left...user chooses fifa18...and then in the next dropdown he can choose payment with paypal or skrill..

every choice that he makes needs to generate a different link

Let's say the result is
XBOX ---> FIFA18 ---> PAYPAL

a link like this (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/fifa-18/bwpkgqv97n7n) needs to be stored inside

```
<a href="#"><i class="fab fa-paypal"></i></a>
```

so that user can navigate to it...

I have no idea how to code this in javascript. I'm basically new to it and i'm really lost.

I tried something like this:

```
function generateLink(){
var value1 = document.getElementById("ddvalue1").value;
var value2 = document.getElementById("ddvalue2").value;
var value3 = document.getElementById("ddvalue3").value;

if (value1 == "xbox" && value2 == "fifa18" && value3= "paypal")
{
    $("pastehere").append("<b>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/fifa-18/bwpkgqv97n7n</b>");
}
}
```

Please help me solve this, im desperate

Comment: you have a lot of duplicated IDs.....

Comment: So, there's a bit to unpack here to hopefully get you moving in the right direction.  If you want users to select something from a list you can use the select/option element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) or a list of radio buttons (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) or just go wild with checkboxes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) -- individual links/anchor tags just make things harder to manage and code around...

Comment: ... then once you decide on how you want to present your choices, you can write the code to accommodate the interaction.  After that, if you want to update the link with a new path you need to target the anchor tag `<a>` itself.  So, drop an ID on your anchor tag and update the href `<a id="paypal" href="#">...</a>` -- `document.getElementById('paypal').href='https://www.micro... ;`

Comment: There is also the aspect of hiding/showing options based on previous selections.  So, if you go with select/option, wait for a change of the console list and test against that to show if you display xBox, PS, or whatever games (bonus points: make sure to not add in games for the wrong console if the user switches choices later in the workflow)

Comment: @Doug so to start, i need to change my <div class> drop downs to select ?

Comment: That'd definitely make things easier -- I'm not certain what bootstrap does for select lists, but using the classic HTML element will make getting the value (and even waiting for the value to change) cleaner

Comment: This is an example of what I think you're trying to go with as per the description of your question: https://jsfiddle.net/dLLow0bw/38/ I hope it's not too confusing, but if you run into anything that doesn't make sense, I can try to elaborate or Google can help if I'm not available.

Comment: updated the fiddle a bit more --> https://jsfiddle.net/dLLow0bw/42/

Comment: @Doug yeh this is exactly what i'm looking for...hopefully i can tweak this into bootstrap dropdown because i like it way more